# How do I use mortars?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I know that my ship has mortars, but I haven't figured out how I actually use the damn things. I must have missed a tutorial popup, and I didn't find any way to fire them by trying out stuff randomly.

I know that most weapon switching happens by looking in a specific direction relative to my ship, or by not aiming the cannons using the left trigger. But I didn't find any combination that would fire the mortars.

Answer (score 26):

To use the mortars, first zoom in using the Mortar Zoom button. This will zoom in as if you were using the spyglass with the addition of a target circle. Move the target with the right thumb stick and, when you are satisfied with your target, press Fire to shoot. The target circle will turn red when an opponent is within range.

---

### Buttons

#### Mortar Zoom

- Wii U: L
- PS3: L2
- PS4: L1
- Xbox: Left bumper
- PC: <kbd>Q</kbd> (hold)

#### Fire

- Wii U: ZR
- PS3: R1
- PS4: R2
- Xbox: Right trigger
- PC: <kbd>LMB</kbd>

Comment: I'm extrapolating the controls based on the Wii U controls. If there are mistakes (or you know the keyboard keys), feel free to edit

Comment: Yep as said there (I'm on xbox) the left bumper is to aim the mortar, there's a white circle where it will land (turns RED over enemies) then right trigger to fire! The eye glass is the right bumper and the mechanic is the same basically! Damn useful that mortar!

Comment: Not as good as crashing into them and then a point blank volley of heavy shot followed up with mini cannon against the exposed weak spots. Gives you something to do while approaching though. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

On PS3 default settings (as I have not changed anything) it is L2 to aim since L1 is for round shots, and R1 to fire while you are looking in the mortar scope.

Answer (score -3):

Left trigger (Xbox) L1 (PS3/4)

Answer (score -3):

On the ps3 it's L2 to aim then R2 to fire.

Comment: This is wrong. L1 to aim.